# Upload file to HDFS using DFSClient on Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to upload/write a file to my HDFS using the DFSClient bundled with Hadoop however I'm being unsuccessful at it, the following code actually creates the file in the HDFS but it's empty (size 0), getting the file and seeing it contents I can confirm it's empty.

How can I debug this behaviour? I've confirmed my local file "dilox.txt" contains the text, and that the loop for my buffer does iterate, my theory is that the output buffer created  by client.create() is not sending anything back to the HDFS.

Please note that I'm not running this inside a Hadoop job, but outside.

Relevant code:

```
String hdfsUrl = "hdfs://1.2.3.4:8020/user/hadoop";

Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", hdfsUrl);
DFSClient client = new DFSClient(new URI(hdfsUrl), conf);


OutputStream out = null;
InputStream in = null;
try {
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(client.create(destinationFilename, true));
    in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("dilox.txt"));

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    int len = 0;
    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
} finally {
    if (client != null) {
        client.close();
    }
    if (in != null) {
        in.close();
    }
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't say anything about copying files with DFSClient but you can use [FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html)'s methods for that purposes:

- `copyFromLocalFile(Path src, Path dst)` - copy file from local file
  system to HDFS
- `moveFromLocalFile(Path src, Path dst)` - move file from
  local file system to HDFS

For example:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("/home/user/test.txt"), new Path("/hadoop/test.txt"));
```

Also you can write files via output stream:

```
FSDataOutputStream outStream = fs.create(new Path("/hadoop/test.txt"));
outStream.write(buffer);
outStream.close();
```

Futhermore there are many useful methods for file copying between local and distributed file systems in classes [FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) and [FileUtil](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change the finally block order

```
finally {
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
    if (in != null) {
        in.close();
    }
    if (client != null) {
        client.close();
    }
}
```